# What informations can be retrieved about a mail that was not delivered?

Tags: email, logging, zimbra

During the migration from our old mail server to Zimbra 8.6, we created a number of Distribution Lists, however, for some reason (our fault probably), one of those list which was supposed to hold 4 email adresses was empty, and so the mails addressed to this particular distribution list were not delivered to the corresponding email adresses.

Issue was quickly solved, but I am currently trying to retrieve as much information as possible about those lost mails, all I could find for now was in the zimbra.log files (which is a great start) : IP adresses of sending servers, name of sending addresses...

Interesting lines found in zimbra.log-date files :

```
Dec  2 04:35:01 ourmailserver postfix/smtpd[24292]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from distantmailserver.com[distantserverIP]: <incommingmailadress@domain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<incommingmailadress@domain.com> to=<ourdistributionlist@domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<distantmailserver.com>
Dec  2 04:35:01 ourmailserver postfix/smtpd[24292]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from distantmailserver.com[distantserverIP]: <incommingmailadress@domain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024; from=<incommingmailadress@domain.com> to=<ourdistributionlist@domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<distantmailserver.com>
Dec  2 04:35:01 ourmailserver postfix/smtpd[24292]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from distantmailserver.com[distantserverIP]: 550 5.1.1 <ourdistributionlist@domain.com>: Recipient address rejected: ourdomain.com; from=<incommingmailadress@domain.com> to=<ourdistributionlist@domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<distantmailserver.com>
```

Does someone know if I can find something else in another log? Like maybe the subject of those messages?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't be able to find more info, as the message is rejected before any data was transferred. Every SMTP mail session begins with sending the sender and receiver and only when that succeeded the rest of the e-mail is transferred.